# how to omit @XmlRootElement from XML output with Jersey?

Tags: xml, jersey

How to omit @XmlRootElement from XML output with Jersey?

How do I output the following XML from Jersey JAX-B:

```
 <Element>sometext</Element>
```

If I have a POJO called element with a member variable, the field name becomes part of the XML. e.g.

```
<Element>
    <field>sometext</field>
</Element>
```

Similarly if I name the field element I will have unnecessary tags for POJO name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing `@XmlElement`, you could leverage `@XmlValue` to get the desired result.  It corresponds to mapping an object to a complex type with simple content.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="Element")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element { 

    @XmlValue
    private String field;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html